# Can you use the relation when creating a new QueryBuilder expression for a datasource?

Tags: google-app-maker

Can you create a one-one relationship and use the other end in the query builder expression when creating a new data source based on either model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The feature called [Relation Filtering](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations#relation_filtering).

Also you can use hints (Ctrl+Space) in Query Builder to see the filtering options.